# De Rham cohomology ring of flag bundles/manifolds in Bott and Tu

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles

I'm trying to understand the result for the de Rham cohomology ring of flag manifolds in *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by Bott and Tu. I'm sort of starting from the result and working backwards to pick up what I need, and I thought I had and understanding of the result in hand, but this point is confusing me. At the bottom of pg. 284 they have the result for flag bundles:

$$ H^* (Fl(E)) = H^* (M)[x_1,...,x_n]\diagup \left( \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_i ) = c(E) \right) $$

and immediately below this they specialize to a flag manifold:

$$ H^* (Fl(V)) = \mathbb{R} [x_1 , ... , x_n] \diagup \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1 + x_i) = 1 \right) .$$

I think their notation is confusing me slightly. They use parenthesis for the ideal generated by an element. So in the flag manifold expression, the Chern classes are all $0$, hence the total Chern class is $1$, and we're quotienting by the ideal generated by $1$. But this should be the whole ring, so the cohomology ring should be trivial. This seems unlikely to me, and they keep expressing the result in this seemingly-odd form instead of saying "it's trivial" so I feel as though I'm misunderstanding some key fact and misinterpreting this result. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are quotienting by the ideal generated by the relations implied by the total Chern class being one (equivalently, the ideal generated by all symmetric polynomials in the $x_i$). This is very different from quotienting by the ideal generated by $1$. Work out very explicitly what this implies the Betti numbers are for small $n$ to see the difference.

Comment: My algebra is a bit weak so I may have to read up a bit before I understand the distinction clearly, but that makes more sense. Thank you.